# Round values in my format php

Tags: php, rounding

How can i round values in nex format ?

- 101.10, 101.11, 101.12, 101.13, 101.14

to 101.10, and

- 101.15, 101.16, 101.17, 101.18, 101.19

to 101.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is eg. `round( 101.11, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)`

The results will be:

```
101.11 101.1
101.12 101.1
101.13 101.1
101.14 101.1
101.15 101.2
101.16 101.2
101.17 101.2
101.18 101.2
101.19 101.2
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter in round()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php